# is there a way to return the points for the add,sub,mul functions rather than the string?

Tags: python

My program is A simple representation of a point in 2d space.

im getting the exact output but for the functions add, sub, mul it says the 'str' object has no attribute 'x.'
How do I return the points and not the strings?

```
class Point:
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.x=x
    self.y=y

  def __str__(self):
    return_string = "Instance of Point\n\n"
    return_string += f"x: {self.x}\ny: {self.y}"
    return return_string

  def __add__(self, other):
    print("Instance of Point\n")
    return(f"x: {self.x + other.x}\ny: {self.y+other.y}")

  def __sub__(self,other):
    print("Instance of Point\n")
    return(f"x: {self.x - other.x}\ny: {self.y-other.y}")

  def __mul__(self, other):
    print("Instance of Point\n")
    return(f"x: {self.x * other.x}\ny: {self.y * other.y}")

  def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.x == other.x and self.y == other.y:
      return True
    else:
      return False
    
  """ A simple representation of a point in 2d space"""
  pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
  point_one = Point(3,2)
  print(point_one)
  print()
  point_two = Point(5,3)
  print(point_two)
  print()
  point_three = point_one + point_two
  print(point_three)
  print()
  point_four = point_one - point_two
  print(point_four)
  print()
  point_five = point_one * point_two
  print(point_five)
  print()
  print(point_one == point_two) # prints False

  # The above should print out the following...
  """  
  Instance of Point

  x: 3
  y: 2
  
  Instance of Point
  
  x: 5
  y: 3
  
  Instance of Point
  
  x: 8
  y: 5
  
  Instance of Point
  
  x: -2
  y: -1
  
  Instance of Point
  
  x: 15
  y: 6

  False
  """
```

Comment: quick note. conventional standard indentation is 4 spaces...

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, only the `__eq__` method correctly returns a boolean. All other dunder methods (`__add__`, etc.) return *strings*. They should return `Point` instances. For example:

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return Point(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
```

And beware, on a mathematical point of view your additions and substraction closely look like vector operations, but this kind of multiplication (or division) does not exist...